# How to export products with tier prices directly via database using SQL?

Tags: magento2, database, sql, magento2.4

I want to export these data from my Magento 2.4:

- Status
- Product Name
- SKU
- Price
- Advanced Pricing
- Quantity

How could I do it via SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this script you might have almost all the information, just the stock qty is missing, but with the other script, you might have the stock too.

### Price

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0;
```

### Stock

Filtered by only simple products.

```
SELECT sku,qty FROM cataloginventory_stock_item stock INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity e ON e.entity_id=stock.product_id AND e.type_id='simple';
```